# Why does this Julia macro _not_ require `esc`?

Tags: macros, julia, hygiene

I found an example of an `unless` macro in Julia [here](https://gitter.im/JuliaLangEs/julialang-es/archives/2015/08/01) written as follows:

```
macro unless(test, branch)
  quote
    if !$test
      $branch
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I try to use it, it fails (apparently there is a hygiene problem, but I can't figure it out exactly). Here is the test that I used:

```
x, y = 0, 1
@unless (x == 5) begin   # should execute
  y = 3
end
@unless (x == 0) begin   # should not execute
  y = 5
end
@assert y == 3           # FAILS! SAYS y is 0
```

Now I can make this work by escaping *only* the branch, not the test:

```
macro unless(test, branch)
  quote
    if !$test
      $(esc(branch))
    end
  end
end
```

My question is: why does it suffice to only escape the branch but not the test? Now I did try macroexpanding. In the first case, without the `esc`, I get this:

```
julia> macroexpand(:(@unless (x == 5) begin y = 3 end))
quote  # none, line 3:
    if !(x == 5) # none, line 4:
        begin  # none, line 1:
            #2#y = 3
       end
    end
end
```

Now even though *neither* macro parameter was escaped, ONLY the `y` was gensymed! Can anyone explain why this was the case? (I know that the second version works because when I escape the branch, The y doesn't get gensymed and the macro expands to `y = 3` as expected. But I'm totally at a loss as to why the `x` was not gensymed even though there was no use of `esc`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to Julia doc:

> Variables within a macro result are classified as either local or
>   global. A variable is considered local if it is assigned to (and not
>   declared global), declared local, or used as a function argument name.
>   Otherwise, it is considered global....

So in this case `test` part does not assign anything therefore it's variables considered global, but in `branch` part, `y` got assigned thus it is considered local and assigning new value to it do not change `y` in the module scope.

Comment: Okay, I see, so `x` is classified as global and `y` as local. Globals pass through without being gensymed. Locals get gensymed. Escaping either prevents the gensymming, but is unnecessary for globals. Makes sense, but it's not quite obvious. :)